# Select Command in a procedure in SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this piece of code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MOSTRA_LOG (P_CODIGO_CLIENTE CLIENTE.CODIGO_CLIENTE%TYPE,N_LOG OUT, CODIGO_CLIENTE OUT, EMAIL OUT,TELEFONE OUT, NOME OUT, TIPO OUT) IS
BEGIN
SELECT (N_LOG, CODIGO_CLIENTE, EMAIL ,TELEFONE, NOME, TIPO) FROM LOG WHERE
(CODIGO_CLIENTE=P_CODIGO_CLIENTE);
END;
```

I know a procedure isn't the optimal thing to do but it is required in my case. It complains about an into clause that needs to be added, however I have nothing to "select into".

All I want basically is to show on the screen everything from the table LOG with the CODIGO_CLIENTE sent as a parameter.

EDIT:
After a suggestion I changed it to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MOSTRA_LOG (P_CODIGO_CLIENTE CLIENTE.CODIGO_CLIENTE%TYPE, N_LOGO OUT INTEGER, CODIGO_CLIENTEO OUT INTEGER, EMAILO OUT VARCHAR(30), TELEFONEO OUT NUMERIC(9,0), NOMEO OUT VARCHAR(50), TIPOO OUT VARCHAR(20)) IS
BEGIN
SELECT (N_LOG into N_LOGO, CODIGO_CLIENTE into CODIGO_CLIENTEO, EMAIL into EMAILO, TELEFONE into TELEFONEO, NOME into NOMEO, TIPO into TIPOO) FROM LOG WHERE (CODIGO_CLIENTE=P_CODIGO_CLIENTE);
END;
```

It's still going wrong saying it expects a symbol when it encountered "(".

Comment: By "shown on the screen" do you mean outputting with dbms_output? You could declare a loop and output straight from the procedure in that case.

Comment: No, just like you would with a simple select, so you can see the tables created with the lines existing in LOG table.

Comment: Sorry,check the answer again, i put a `)` in bad place

Comment: I resolved the problem by splitting every SELECT x INTO x FROM LOG for every parameter. How do I use these now? When I call the procedure?

Comment: but, your select return multiple rows?, and you want to show your log data as a select?

Comment: Yes, I can explain it a little better. LOG has the changes applied to table CLIENTE. It does this with a trigger which is tested and working. Now what I want is to show all the lines in LOG (like you would with a normal select from a table) with a procedure.

Comment: And it has to be a procedure, could be a function?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way using `collections`:

First you must create the collection where you will store your LOG query results:

```
CREATE TYPE LOG_OBJECT AS OBJECT
       (CODIGO_CLIENTEO INTEGER,
        EMAILO VARCHAR (30),
        TELEFONEO NUMERIC (9, 0),
        NOMEO VARCHAR (50),
        TIPOO VARCHAR (20));

CREATE TYPE LOG_TABLE AS TABLE OF LOG_OBJECT;
```

Later you create your procedure like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MOSTRA_LOG (P_CODIGO_CLIENTE CLIENTE.CODIGO_CLIENTE%TYPE, LOG_T OUT LOG_TABLE) IS
BEGIN
SELECT LOG_OBJECT(N_LOG, CODIGO_CLIENTE, EMAIL ,TELEFONE, NOME, TIPO) BULK COLLECT INTO  LOG_T FROM LOG WHERE
(CODIGO_CLIENTE=P_CODIGO_CLIENTE);
END;
```

When procedure is created you can use the collection like it was a table. For example below anonymus block prints total of rows of your query on LOG table:

```
DECLARE
   LOG_T LOG_TABLE;
   total   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   mostra_log (LOG_T); --invoke the procedure and fill the collection
   SELECT COUNT (*) INTO total FROM TABLE (LOG_T); -- get count of collection returned
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (total);
END;
```